# Run script block with option defining filename

Tags: rundeck

I am trying to create a rundeck job where I specify the name of a .bat file on a remote server, that I want to execute on that remote server.  We don't have an execution node on that server, so I'm using invoke-command to run the job on that (Windows) server.  I can run the job fine if I hardcode the file path in the command window.

I'd like to add an option to allow the user to specify the location of the .bat file, to make it easier to create new jobs (we will probably have to create lots of jobs like this).

Right now my workflow is the single command:

```
Invoke-command -Authentication kerberos -ComputerName <servername> -ScriptBlock{<filename>}
```

That works, but I cannot figure out how to get the option (`${option.prog_run}`) to interact with this; either I get a powershell error saying I specified it wrong, or it doesn't actually run anything.

This will "succeed", but doesn't actually run the file:

```
Invoke-command -Authentication kerberos -ComputerName s12zapap01880 -ScriptBlock{start-process ${option.prog_run} }
```

This will fail, with an error like so:

```
 16:28:00   At line:1 char:123 
 16:28:00   + ... <servername>'-ScriptBlock{<filename.bat>' } 
 16:28:00   +                                               ~ 
 16:28:00   Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
```

That suggests that I'm not escaping the { } correctly, perhaps, but I'm not sure how.  What is the proper way to include an option here?

Comment: The error says something related to quotes, check carefully your step. Another option that you have is using the inline script, to use with Powershell click on "Inline Script" step, click on "Advanced", in "Invocation String" put "Powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass " (without quotes) and in "File Extension" put "ps1" (without quotes too) and put your script in the textbox. With that you can use options in this format: @option.myoption@ I did make a little example using inline script and command step, check it: https://pastebin.com/GyZ1fEkR

Comment: @ReinerRDECK Ah, that's a good point, and I can still execute it on the remote server that way. I'll take a look at it, thanks!